# Xcode - Label outlet is nil in tab bar item views

Tags: xcode, uitableview, segue, uitabbar

I have a split view controller, the cell of the table view has a segue to a tab bar that has a segue to its view controllers

The problem is when I pass data to the destinationViewController, the data is successfully passed, but the label outlet in this view is nil.

This is the prepareForSegue method in the TableViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        println("segue happened")
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let patient = patients[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController).viewControllers![0] as personalViewController
            controller.patient = patient
        }
    }
```

This is the personalViewController (the first tab)

```
import UIKit

class personalViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!

@IBAction func btnButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let temp = self.patient
    self.patient = temp
}

var patient : Patient? {
    didSet {
        println("patient didSet")
        self.setData()
    }
}

[...]

func setData() {
    println( self.lblName == nil ) // true when selecting an element in table view but false if I set data using btnButton button
    println( self.patient!.name ) // always set correctly
    if lblName != nil { // had to add this line to prevent crash
        lblName.text = patient!.name
    }
    // The previous line crashes when using table view for navigation
    // it does not crash when clicking a button (btnButton)
}

}
```

Whenever I user the outlet lblName in the `didSet` of patient (by clicking a table cell) I get nil. However, if I create a button that sets lblName within that view it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing, after spending a whole day trying to figure this out it seems I was calling the setData method before the view was initialized.

Instead of calling the setData method in the didSet of the patient property, instead I should have done it in the viewDidLoad method of the UIViewController

```
var patient : Patient?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    println( "Personal View Did Load");
    setData()
}
```